# How do I use a competed function in Vue to order json alphabetically?

Tags: json, vue.js

How do I display category titles in alphabetical order using v-for?

I assume I should use a computed function but I don't know how to rearrange the data object.

```
<template>
  <div> 
    <h3>Categories</h3>
    <ul>
       <li v-for="category in orderItems" :key="category.id">
         {{ category.title }}
       </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      categories: [
        {
          title: "chicken"
          id: 1
        },
        {
          title: "beef"
          id: 2
        },
        {
          title: "soup"
          id: 3
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    orderItems: function() {
      const results = this.categories.....
      return results;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const results = this.categories.slice().sort((a, b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
orderItems: function() {
  function compare(a, b) {
    let ac = a.title.toLowerCase();
    let bc = b.title.toLowerCase();
    if (ac < bc)
      return -1;
    if (ac > bc)
      return 1;
    return 0;  
  }
  return this.categories.sort(compare);
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.